# Mute the right channel of microphone

Tags: ubuntu, microphone

I have problem with my microphone.
When I tried to record something I heard only noise.
I searched in google for a solution and I found some answer that says that I need to mute one channel of my mic (right/left, suggested right).
So I downloaded `pavucontrol` and I tried to mute the right channel, it works fine for a second, I can hear myself on recording , and the volume bar detect the input, but after a second of recording the channel return to its previous state, (100% right and left).
I tried also to mute the left channel but it also returns to its previous state.

I tried to search in google for a solution to mute one channel but I didn't find anything.
I found some lines that says things about that but nothing helpful.
I tried via alsa mixer but I couldn't find a way to mute one channel.

I use ubuntu 16.04, on Lenovo Ideapad 310.

Comment: What microphone are you using? A professional one with a balanced XLR plug? If yes, a better option may be an ALSA `route` plugin that inverts one channel and adds it to the other channel. As for the muting problem, do the channel controls also change back? In `alsamixer`, too? Does your desktop have sound control similar to `pavucontrol`, and is it active?

Comment: @dirkt How can I tell which microphone I have? , in `pavucontrol` written `analog`, and yes the controls also change back also i alsa mixer. I didn't install any sound control except `pavucontrol` there is the basic that came with Ubuntu

Comment: You know the brand and model of your microphone, don't you? And there should be a product description, or you can find one online. If the controls are moving, *something* most move them. So some application you are running thinks it needs to control the audio. Culprit candidates are in whatever desktop you are using.